# How to run my custom ajax after woocommerce ajax add_to_cart?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a ajax file handle after click add_to_cart. but my problem is my ajax file always run before woocommerce file (like my picture). How to run my custom ajax after woocommerce ajax add_to_cart ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

However its not a good practice, you can try the below code :

```
$('.add_to_cart_button').on('click',function(){
    /** write your code here **/            
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have handled this problem. I am using   :jQuery('body').on('added_to_cart',function() { // do anything }
and it is working now. thanks your answer

Comment: That is what I have said.

Comment: no. If you use click event then your event not run after woocommerce ajax

Answer (score 0):

So I realize this post is old but I am experience the same problem. I used setTimeout to delay the ajax request by 500ms

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
console.log('ajax-minicart.js loaded');
// What event do we want our AJAX to fire on? ADDING A PRODUCT TO CART.
$('.ajax_add_to_cart').on('click', function () {
    // Fix
    setTimeout( function () {
        console.log('clicked');

        // What data do we need to send? URL TO AJAX, ACTIONS
        $.post(my_ajax_obj.ajax_url, {
            _ajax_nonce: my_ajax_obj.nonce,
            action: 'update_minicart',
        }, function(response) {
            // What do we want to do with response? REFRESH CART
            console.log(response);
            $('.cart-container').html(response);
        });     
    }, 500);
});
```

});

I'm not sure of the stability or future-proofing of this fix but it works for now. I'd appreciate any information on why this happens myself.

Comment: Please use:
`jQuery('body').on('added_to_cart',function() { // do anything }`
That's all!

Comment: @huykon225 thanks, I swear I tried this multiple times but it wouldn't work. Working now. Do you have any reference to documentation to this? I'd like to know how the added_to_cart event listener works with woocommece.

Comment: you can read more in core of woocommerce: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js
I hope you understand and useful for you. 
Best